# sending an email with a previous page as the content in asp.net c# environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms, mailmessage

Okay so, I can send the current pages contents to email just fine, formatting it is a bit strange  and ends up a little differently than expected, but I am getting the hang of it.

What I am currently wanting to do is to **send and access a previous pages entire formatted form within the current one (I am thinking this can be done with a session object) and then send this to email**. This includes user input into text boxes etc (which I am currently persisting across the pages via session objects [if this matters]).

I have tried to search google and this site with nothing that really solves these issues, and there are several of them.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

For clarity, here is the process I am utilizing to send the current page via email:

```
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter( );
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter( sw );
    MAIN.RenderControl( w );
    string s = sw.GetStringBuilder( ).ToString( );

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage( );
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.To.Add( new MailAddress( Session["eMail"].ToString( ) ) );
    message.Subject = "foo bar";
    message.From = new MailAddress( "email@email.com" );
    message.Body = s; //this would be filled with the previous page
```

So basically, the `message.Body` would be the form contents (formatted and with all user content) of a previous page.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I do not mean the literal previous page before the one you would currently be on, I mean a page that was previous in the process to getting to this page (in my case it is the second page in the process and the email will be sent at the fourth page).

Comment: Seems like you've completed the hard part.  Would you mind posting how you did it?  I guess it's not as simple as just working with the **Page** object; if it was, you could just replace with **Page.PreviousPage** and you'd be done.

Comment: you have to understand that in asp.net the controls maintain their state with viewstate session will be saved on sever and is a burden to server while viewstate is saved in client machine. Technically all the controls viewstate is enabled by default. Now if you want the contents of previous page you can either use page.previouspage or save previous page body content to ViewState["Body"]

Comment: @dbaseman - do you mean how i achieved sending the current page? Well in this case, I utilized one of my div's to be rendered with the HtmlTextWriter object. That being my main div. So I set runat="server" for my main div and was good to go. I guess I need to be clear, I do not mean the literal previous page before the one you would currently be on, I mean a page that was previous in the process to getting to this page (in my case it is the second page in the process and the email will be sent at the fourth page).

Comment: @ghostcake gotcha... nice.  So what happens if you apply that same method on Page.PreviousPage?

Comment: @dbaseman - ah my edit got here too late :p    but yeah in this case, the Page.PreviousPage refers literally to the previous page, and I am trying to access A previous page (not necessarily the page before the page I am currently on). However, does the page class allow access to a method that can access another page (but not necessarily the previous page to the one you are currently on)?

Comment: @skhurams - so if i were to save the body content within viewstate, would i be able to access that in a new page with all the user input values intact and then be able to format it appropriately with HtmlTextWriter? I have never worked too much with viewstate, mainly just session and query string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know all the parameters your previous page was given, you can create an instance of your page and generate it's HTML.

I've written a blog post about it here:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2009/09/14/a-simple-solution-to-viewing-a-preview-of-any-page-in-your-site

Basically this means tapping into the ASP.Net runtime and executing the page through its lifecycle - if your page has any public properties such as content ID's etc you can set them as part of this.

```
Page tempPage = new Views.Blog.BlogDetail();
tempPage.PageIntro = intro;
tempPage.PageContent = content;

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(tempPage, sw, false);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sw.ToString()))
{
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Obviously this is not getting the previous page, but instead generating it all over again and getting its content.

Comment: Interesting! By this though, it looks as though I will have to programatically place all the values back in this new instance of the page? Am I correct with this assumption. _*cringes at the thought of repopulating 50+ input fields._

Comment: yes you are correct. however if you use something similar to Server.Transfer in moving between your two pages, all the previous page's fields should be available under ["Page.PreviousPage"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

Comment: This is a problem though I think, since Page.PreviousPage only accesses the previous page  to the one that you would currently be on (am I correct with this?). I will need access to a page that was accessed before the page that will be sending the email, but not the page that was directly before the page you are currently on.

Comment: You are correct, but there is nothing stopping you from taking this on first landing, and storing it in a local page variable or session/profile state.

Comment: Yeah for sure, so I understand that I can save the form of the current page via `Page.Form`. I save this into a session object - `Session["page"] = Page.Form;`. However, Retrieving it and then getting it to be rendered is a problem. Typically I do this via     `StringWriter sw = new StringWriter( );
 HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter( sw );
 MAIN.RenderControl( w );`. I need to instead of using 'Main' (which is the id of my div I am using to render) I want to use the Page.Form stored in my session object. Is there a way to properly convert this?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try jumping through any hoops to get the previous page.  Since you are in some kind of page/workflow I suggest that you store the state that you are after (should you not be doing that now) and then send the e-mail containing the state rendered appropriately.

For instance: let's say the previous page had some comment on it and a comment date.  You could then save that *state* (the comment and date) in, say, a database and then pick it up in the next page where you do the e-mail sending.

If a database is overkill you could store it in the session state and then remove it once used.

Comment: I don't think I understand viewstate very well. Do you have any resources on how it saves the values and data within the page?

Comment: Not viewstate :) --- rather the actual state that is relevant.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ahh, thanks for the edit. I have saved a lot of the values via session state, however I am also needing to save the entire page itself (by this I mean the html within the page too). So that when I send the email, they see a literal representation of the page where they input those values. So not only will they be seeing the values, but the entire page itself with the values still within it. I know how to send an email with the html of the current page you are on, but not a previous page within the workflow, this is the primary issue I am having.

Comment: That's my point.  I wouldn't recommend trying to send the actual html.  If you *can* render it eaasily from scratch then fair enough; else just render something relevant that contains the required state.

Comment: ah, I see. Well unfortunately I am required to send the literal representation of said page.

Comment: bummer :) --- you *could* always render the html yourself so that it looks the same.  Unfortunately it sounds like you are stuck with an unreasonable "requirement".